# Can a Table of Contents be generated in Publisher?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-publisher

I have a decent amount of content already typed up with headers on most pages.  I would like to create a generated Table of Contents based off of these headers.  Is this possible, and if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

#### I would like to create a generated Table of Contents based off of these headers

You cannot automatically create a table of contents - this feature is not available in Publisher.

The following instructions show you how to manually create a TOC. It looks like you will have to copy and paste your headings ...

> **Insert a table of contents in Publisher**
>
> For a little extra work—and a big payoff—you can create a table of
>   contents in Publisher. Begin by adding a text box and use
>   right-aligned tabs with leaders. Leaders are the dots, dashes, or
>   lines that follow the chapter or section titles in a table of contents
>   and that line up those titles with page numbers.
>
> [image: Create a table of contents (TOC) using tab stops and leaders.]
>
> 1. Click Home > Draw Text Box.
> 2. In your publication, click where you want one corner of the text to appear, and then drag diagonally until you have the box size that
>      you want.
> 3. Type the title of your table of contents, and then press ENTER.
> 4. Double-click the horizontal ruler where you want the page number to appear.
> 5. In the Tabs dialog box, click Right, choose your Leader style, and then click OK.
> 6. Now type your TOC entry; for example: Chapter 1, press TAB to insert the leader and type the page number.

Source [Insert a table of contents in Publisher](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-table-of-contents-in-Publisher-f321c851-a52a-4118-8f84-0cf21e995d30)

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for a quick fix for a colleagues problem couldn't find a solution elsewhere, so posting my own solution to simulate TOC using script with PowerShell Version 5 on Win7 with Publisher 2010.

TOC added in between page 2 and 3 where page 1 was a title cover page and 2 a welcome page. The title was always text box shape 1. to keep alignment style a monospaced font was used for TOC.

If you are using Standard Publisher Page Part Headings then the following could be substituted variable $TOCAdd

```
$Heading_Geometric_Title_Text = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($pge).Shapes(1).GroupItems[3].TextFrame.TextRange.Text
$Heading_Geometric_Subtitle_Text = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($pge).Shapes(1).GroupItems[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Text

$Heading_Brackets_Title_Text = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($pge).Shapes(1).GroupItems[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Text
$Heading_Brackets_Subtitle_Text = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($pge).Shapes(1).GroupItems[5].TextFrame.TextRange.Text

$Heading_Pure_Title_Text = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($pge).Shapes(1).GroupItems[3].TextFrame.TextRange.Text
$Heading_Pure_Subtitle_Text = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($pge).Shapes(1).GroupItems[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

#

```
# Path to Publisher document
$FileName = "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Publication_1.pub"
$Publisher=NEW-Object –comobject Publisher.Application

# Following line sets whether file is opened visible or not.
$Publisher.ActiveWindow.visible = 1

# Open Publisher Document
$Publisher.open($FileName)

# Check how Many Pages in document
$count = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages.Count

# How Many TOC Pages required in document for the amount of titles (assume 17 per page)
    $TOCPages = [math]::Round($count/17)

# New Page Count including TOC required in document
    $countINC = $count += $TOCPages

# Add TOC pages required insert Page(s) after last Pre page 
    $Pre = 2
    IF ($TOCPages -ge 1) {
    ForEach ( $n in 1..$TOCPages){
    $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages.Add(1,$Pre)
    }

# Add table on TOC Pages
    ForEach ( $n In 1..$TOCPages){
# Insert New Toc from this page No 
    $n += $Pre

# Insert table on the new TOC page with  NumRows:=17, NumColumns:=3, Left:=50, Top:=70, Width:=600, Height:=300
    $TOCPage = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($n).Shapes.AddTable( 17, 3, 50, 75, 600, 300)
# Adjust column widths for table (shape)
    $TOCPage.Table.Columns(1).width = 30  #Item No
    $TOCPage.Table.Columns(2).width = 450 #Item
    $TOCPage.Table.Columns(3).width = 70  #Page No

    #Add Text Box Standard Text (type 1) adjust font size then make it Bold
    $TOCTitle = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($n).Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 360,  26, 150, 25)
    $TOCIndex = ($n -= ($Pre))
    $TOCTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Table of Contents $TOCIndex"
    $TOCTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
    $TOCTitle.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = 1 
    } 
    }
# Identify first page after TOC
    $start = $TOCPages += ($Pre += 1)
# Create TOC Array (Fixed Content First) append to fixed length Char 46 (period)
    $TOCROW1 = 'Title Page'
    $TOCROW2 = 'Welcome to the Catalogue'
    $TOCROW3 = 'Table of Contents'
    $TOCArray = @()
    $TOCRow = "" | Select 'Table of Contents','PageNo'
    $TOCRow.'Table of Contents' = $TOCROW1.PadRight(60,[char]46)
    $TOCRow.PageNo = 1
    $TOCArray = $TOCArray + $TOCRow
    $TOCRow = "" | Select 'Table of Contents','PageNo'
    $TOCRow.'Table of Contents' = $TOCROW2.PadRight(60,[char]46)
    $TOCRow.PageNo = 2
    $TOCArray = $TOCArray + $TOCRow
    $TOCRow = "" | Select 'Table of Contents','PageNo'
    $TOCRow.'Table of Contents' = $TOCROW3.PadRight(60,[char]46)
    $TOCRow.PageNo = 3
    $TOCArray = $TOCArray + $TOCRow

# Use try / catch for page shapes returning error
    try { 
    ForEach ($pge in $Start..$countINC){
    IF ($pge -eq "" ){ Write-Host "Debug"}
    Else{ # Add TOC Array Entries

    $TOCAdd = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($pge).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text 
    $TOCRow = "" | Select 'Table of Contents','PageNo';
    $TOCRow.'Table of Contents' = $TOCAdd.PadRight(60,[char]46)
    $TOCRow.PageNo = $pge
    $TOCArray = $TOCArray + $TOCRow
    }
 }
}

    catch { }

# Debug uncomment following line to View Output of 'Table of Contents' based on the data added in Array variable 'TOCArray'
#    $TOCArray | Format-Table -Wrap -Property 'Table of Contents','PageNo'

# Add TOC entries to TOC (uses monospaced font to get alignment)
    $n = 2
    $q = -1
    $Item =0
    ForEach ($TOC in 1..$TOCPages) {
     $n++
     $q++
     $Row = 0
     $Offset = ($q * $Range)
     $Range  = 17
     $TOCArray | Select-Object -Skip $Offset -First $Range -Property 'Table of Contents','PageNo'| 
    ForEach-Object { 
      $Row++
      $Item++
      $TOCEntry = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($n).Shapes(1).Table.Rows($Row).Cells(1);
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Text = "$Item";
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Size = 12;
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Bold = 1;
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Name = 'Consolas';
      $TOCEntry = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($n).Shapes(1).Table.Rows($Row).Cells(2);
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Text = $_.'Table of Contents'.replace("`r","").ToString()
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Size = 12;
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Bold = 1;
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Name = 'Consolas';
      $TOCEntry = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Pages($n).Shapes(1).Table.Rows($Row).Cells(3);
      #Need to Convert PageNo stored as System.Int32 to String
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Text = $_.PageNo.ToString()
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Size = 12;
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Bold = 1;
      $TOCEntry.TextRange.Font.Name = 'Consolas';
     }
    }
# Save File (and increment versions), then close.
    $v++
    $file = $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Name
    $BaseName = $file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf('.'))
    $strFileName = $BaseName + "_v1" + $v
    $Publisher.ActiveDocument.SaveAs($strFileName)
    $Publisher.ActiveDocument.Close()
    $Publisher.quit()
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Publisher)
```